# How can I connect to a remote SSH host using the `code` command?

Tags: vscode-remote

I can use VS Code's `code` shell command to open local folders from the terminal:

```
code some/folder
```

Can I similarly use the `code` command to open a folder (or file) on a remote SSH host from the terminal, instead of using the "Remote-SSH: Connect to Host" command inside VS Code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
code --remote ssh-remote+hostname /some/dir
```

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/troubleshooting#_connect-to-a-remote-host-from-the-terminal